# Windows Server - many event id 4625 authentication failures

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, security, authentication, dhcp

In a small network environment, we have one Windows Server with Domain Controller, DHCP and DNS.

When every **non-domain** Windows client connects to the network, a lot of 4625 logon failure events are generated on the server. I suppose they are generated by DNS authentication failures, but I'm not sure. There is a related SMBServer error.

If I configure these non-domain clients the DNS to an external resource (8.8.8.8), the problem persists. For example, when the client opens the File Explorer, since the network is the same.

We are not allowed to create a separate subnetwork.

How can I prevent this, since they obscure potential real brute force attacks?

**Event: Authentication error:**
[image: Event: Authentication error]

**Event: SMBServer error**
[image: Event: SMBServer error]

Comment: `suppose they are generated by DNS authentication failures` really? How? What about the data inside the event? What about investigating the issue in an endpoint?

Comment: Can you please provide the full event

Comment: @GregAskew I've attached the events

Comment: @Turdie I've attached the events

Comment: You will need to investigate on the endpoint what is it attempting to access. This could be anything. A shortcut, a script, a scheduled task.

Comment: @GregAskew Every non-domain PC (even personal), without anything configured relating to the newtwork, as soon as you open File Explorer, raises the Events. Maybe a sort of discovery or "broadcasting" stuff happens.

Comment: Is that an excuse for why you don't want to pursue investigating on the offending endpoints? You have the access.

Comment: The failure code 0xC000006D means Incorrect username and password and it looks over NTLM. You can try to disable NTLM according to the guidance provided by Microsoft https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/active-directory-hardening-series-part-1-disabling-ntlmv1/ba-p/3934787

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that clients had previously done access to shared resources and did not save credentials.

The solution who solved my problem was opening File Explorer, going in Folder Options, Tab General, then Clear File Explorer History.